# How to manage multiple output csv formats

Tags: c#, sql, csv, ssis, datamapper

I need to generate output files in multiple csv formats, from data stored in a SQL database. So as an example I have the following data:

```
Order Id | Order Date | PO Number | Total Value
100      | 06/03/2015 | 12345     | £175.50
```

And from this I need to generate two csv files.

The first in the format:

```
orderdate,orderid,ponum,value
06-03-2015,000100,12345,17550
```

the second in this:

```
order number,date,amount,ref
100,060315,£175.50,123456
```

So different field headings, order, format, leading zeros, decimal points etc.

My question is - what options do I have if I want to support many more new (as yet unknown) formats **through configuration** without needing to write/update code?

I believe XPATH could be an approach (and use some third-party tool to manage the mapping etc), but I'm not that familiar with this and it seems a bit clunky. If it were a JSON to CSV mapper then I'd be more comfortable with this.

I was also wondering if SSIS could do the job - but again I'm not too familiar with that.

I could build something (I'm a C#.NET developer) and use string formatters, and provide some UI for this I guess.

Any suggestions, thoughts, experience?

Update:

The requested feature is that a new format could be supported within a few hours, set up by a non-coder, ideally via a configuration file or UI. This may be say a handful per month - but turnaround important.

Comment: You can't define output formats on the fly in SSIS but you can in BIML (which generates SSIS packages based on code). How many formats do you really expect? It's not that slow to custom build in SSIS each time.

Comment: do you need to have it create multiple files at the same time, or could it be like    `Run program > Exit program > change config file > run program again` ?

Comment: Yes DrewJordan if you think is a possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use some open source component for writting the CSV file. See [here](https://tburette.github.io/blog/2014/05/25/so-you-want-to-write-your-own-CSV-code/) why. So the only thing you have to manage is the order of the columns. You could handle that by using dynamic sql which could be generated by some kind of a configuration file. This file could also contain the information needed for the csv component.

Comment: Your link is just an intro into CSV which isn't that helpful :-( Dynamic sql yes an option. I was ideally looking for a framework or tool that gives me 80% of what I need. I know I could build something from scratch but I'd prefer not if there was something I could base it on out there already. Thanks anyway.